# filter mongo document - python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is a view from mongo document. I want to keep only those entries in the document whose key-value is longest. The key value here is a string, So the keys with longest string length should only remain

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a431415c7a981b47ac4ee"), 
    "key" : "http://www.adnansami.com", 
    "value" : "A"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a431415c7a981b47ac4ef"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "BB"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a431d15c7a981b47ac4f0"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "B"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a431d15c7a981b47ac4f1"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "C"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a432515c7a981b47ac4f2"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "BBB"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a432815c7a981b47ac4f3"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "CC"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a432d15c7a981b47ac4f4"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "BBBB"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a433115c7a981b47ac4f5"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "CCC"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a433615c7a981b47ac4f6"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "BBBBB"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a433d15c7a981b47ac4f7"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "CCCC"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a434915c7a981b47ac4f8"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "CCCCC"
}
```

So output should be

```
  { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("58539dc715c7a964817686f9"), 
   "http://www.adnansami.com" : "A "
  }
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a433615c7a981b47ac4f6"), 
    "key" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value" : "BBBBB"
  }
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a434915c7a981b47ac4f8"), 
    "key" : "http://www.machinelearningmastery.com", 
    "value" : "CCCCC"
  }
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be very complex to query in mongo without resorting to some map-reduce operations because of the hash keys. Mongo works very well with an embedded structure where you have a key/value document like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58539dfa15c7a96481768700"),        
    "key": "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value": "AAAAAAAA" 
}
```

instead, so you should consider restructuring your document to make it indexable and more easily searched in MongoDB.

For the above proposed schema, you can apply the aggregation framework where you can use the **[`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#exp._S_strLenCP)** operator in Mongodb 3.4 to calculate the length of the value field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "strLength": { 
                "$strLenCP": "$value"
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "strLength": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$key",
            "value": { "$first": "$value" },
            "doc_id": { "$first": "$_id" }          
        }
    }    
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{ 
    "doc_id": ObjectId("58539dc715c7a964817686f9"),
    "_id" : "http://www.adnansami.com", 
    "value":  "A "      
},
{ 
    "doc_id": ObjectId("58539dd515c7a964817686fc"),
    "_id" : "http://www.movies.yahoo.com",
    "value": "AAAA"     
},
{ 
    "doc_id": ObjectId("58539dfa15c7a96481768700"),
    "_id" : "http://www.leap-networks.com", 
    "value": "AAAAAAAA"     
}
```

Comment: i am getting error `field names in dot notation need to be in quotes at line 3 col 1`, tried editing but is not working

Comment: I have edited the question with the changes, I made in my document. with this changes document I just removed `ratings` from your query. Sorry for delayed response

Comment: I did the same change to the query i.e.. `removed ratings` still not working?

Comment: error message is `assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",
 "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: the problem was with mongo version, which needs mongo 3.4